# dynamically add frame layout into Horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to dynamically add some custom Frame Layout into an Horizontal Scroll View. I was thinking to create in xml the horizontal scroll view with a nested Linear Layout and add with java some Frame Layout. Something like this:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    FrameLayout child = new FrameLayout(this);
    child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card);
    //add this linear layout to the parent
}
```

I've seen some solution using Layout Inflater but, from what i understand, that uses a layout from my resources. Instead, if possibile, i  want to create my Frame layout without xml.

Thanks

EDIT:

here is my xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly? The code you have looks fine. Just add the `FrameLayout`s to the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I'm asking how to add the Frame Layout in the Linear Layout in java. In a few words, i need to replace the comment inside the loop with some real code

Comment: `parent.addView(child);`

Comment: i've tried that way but nothing shows on screen. I've edited the post with also my xml code.

Comment: Please share those attempts in the question, in the future. I would guess, if everything else is correct, that your `card` drawable has no intrinsic dimensions – i.e., no defined size; zero width and height – and `LinearLayout`'s default horizontal `LayoutParams` wrap both dimensions. Since there's nothing else in the `FrameLayout`, it wraps to its background drawable, but since that has zero size, the `FrameLayout` wraps to 0x0. You could either use a drawable with a definite size, or set definite `LayoutParams`; e.g., `parent.addView(child, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));`.

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you had this code:

```
FrameLayout child = new FrameLayout(this);
child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card);
parent.addView(child);
```

Because you haven't specified any `LayoutParams` for this view, the LinearLayout will generate default LayoutParams for you. This is how it does that:

```
@Override
protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    } else if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your LinearLayout is horizontal, so it will use `WRAP_CONTENT` for both dimensions. But your FrameLayout doesn't have any content, so this is the same as 0.

You can manually specify your LayoutParams (using pixel dimensions) by changing your code as follows:

```
FrameLayout child = new FrameLayout(this);
child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200); // px units
child.setLayoutParams(params);

parent.addView(child);
```

Alternatively, you could add content to the FrameLayout in order to give it something to wrap:

```
FrameLayout child = new FrameLayout(this);
child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("hello world");
child.addView(tv);

parent.addView(child);
```